# jQuery Isotope scorll to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I've searched here and in other places, but I couldn't find the answer.

In my website, I use the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin in several pages, and it all works well.

The problem is that in one of the pages, the plugin is only initialized when the user clicks a button. What happens than, is that the page automatically scrolls to the top.

I couldn't find a way to prevent this behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are assigning the click functions by selecting the object's ID as your way of initializing the Isotope, if the button has a hastag as the url, ie:

```
<a id="buttonName" href="#">Click me!</a>
```

Then it will send the page back to the top when you click it. One way to get around this would be to remove the href from your element, and add some css to its class or id that will cause it to display a hand pointer cursor on mouseover.

```
#buttonName {  
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Without seeing a link or the code you are using it's hard to say but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the button is actually an `<li>` that has an `onclick` event handler which initializes the plugin. I also tried `return false;` after the statement that initializes the plugin, but no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

Add a prevent default action to the filter buttons:

```
$('.filterable li a').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but clicking the button doesn't trigger the scrolling to the top behavior. That only happens once the line of code that initializes the plugin executes.